# Read mail and SMS from my application

Tags: android

I was wondering if it's possible to read emails and SMS from an android application I'm developing.
Or even have the chance to add a new menu button to the default mail app in order to pass that particular mail text to my background application that can use it to perform some syntax analysis.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the SMS part you would need to use a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to do that.

This should be a good start: http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/

There are a lot of email clients in the Market. I don't think you will have any luck with accessing the emails.